# Woocommerce / Wordpress - Out Of Hours

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I disable checkout or even access to a store during certain hours? The problem I have is, I'm setting up a online store using WooCommerce, but customers should only be able to place an order during certain times of the day.

Comment: Why? The whole purpose of having an online store is so people can shop 24/7. You are just going to annoy customers

Comment: Do you want to disable the checkout according to the visitor's local timezone? Or according to some specific master timezone?

Comment: Not taking orders over Friday evening to Saturday evening hasn't seemed to have slowed [B & H](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/find/HelpCenter/AboutUs.jsp "B & H") down…

Comment: Sorry, I should have explain it better. This is for a local takeaway business. So the idea is to disable checkout out of business hours.

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve this for a business cafeteria business trying to get off the ground. They only wanted the preorders available during certain times of the day.

I used [Scheduled Content](https://wordpress.org/plugins/scheduled-contnet-by-streama/) plugin... or one like it. I honestly can't remember and the business fell through so the site isn't around anymore to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Catalog Visibility Options](http://www.woothemes.com/products/catalog-visibility-options/) extension which allows you to disable the cart. Sadly, you would have to manually turn it on / off during the day for it to work. You would probably want something more automated.

Answer (score 0):

An easy but dirty way would be to use jQuery to hide the add to cart buttons at a certain time and set a message to say that it's out of hours.

edit: This certainly wouldn't be the most reliable method though.